# ForEach over CSV

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, active-directory

I’ve created a script which exports inactive Azure users into a CSV. This CSV contains users which are in various OU’s within onprem AD as we’re hybrid. I’m trying to create another script which loops over the CSV but only targets users within our “Users OU” and moves them to an “Inactive OU”. Here’s what I have so far but I’m a little stumped. I can’t figure out where or how to add in -Filter SearchBase into this.

```
$inactiveAzure = import-CSV -path “C:\temp\InactiveAzure.csv”

$OUpath = “OU I would like the script to run over” 

$OUTarget = “Inactive OU example”

ForEach($users in $inactiveAzure) {
    Get-ADuser -Identity $users.onPremisesSamAccountName | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $OUTarget
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I’ve tried adding SearchBase into the script but can’t get it to work. I’m not entirely sure how to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the `*-AD*` cmdlets take a `-SearchBase` parameter with which you can limit the search to a particular container or subtree:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($users.onPremisesSamAccountName)'" -SearchBase $OU | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $OUTarget
```

When using the `-Filter` option, `Get-ADUser` will fail *silently* if no matching users are found in the given OU, otherwise the user object will be piped to `Move-ADObject` as expected

Comment: That’s great! Tested it out and works perfectly. Thank you very much. Is there anyway I can implement Disable-ADAccount into the same script?

Comment: @Ackerman You can add `-PassThru` to `Move-ADObject` to make it output the object again so you can pipe it to `Disable-ADAccount`